# How to remove a VC then add another VC directly afterward

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have a Main VC (call this VC A), that has a child VC (VC B). When I tap a button on VC B I dismiss it as a child VC, however once this is done I would like to instantiate another VC (VC C). I do this by creating a bool on VC B which, if true calls a function on VC A that creates a new child VC (VC C). All of the function calls are being made however the VC C never gets added. Below I have added the code:

VC B:

```
 func removeAnimate()
{

    self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()

    didTransition = true

    if didTransition == true {
       callAddVC()
    }

}

func callAddVC() {
    let instVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

    instVC.addVC()
}
```

VC A:

```
  func addVC () {


    let popvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentsTabViewController") as! CommentsTabViewController

    self.addChildViewController(popvc)
    popvc.view.center = self.view.center

    popvc.view.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 337, height: 503)

    self.view.addSubview(popvc.view)

    popvc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            }
```

Comment: How are you adding the initial popover?

Comment: utilizing the same code in the addVC() function once VC A  is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `ViewController A (MainViewController)` on the `callAddVC()`, Which is wrong. You are not using existing instance of the `ViewController A`

You have to pass the `Viewcontroller A` instance while adding a `Viewcontroller B`

**Viewcontroller A**

```
  let viewControllerB = // Get the instance of UIViewControllerB from storyboard
  viewControllerB.vcA = self
```

**Viewcontroller B**

```
  class UIViewControllerB {
        weak var vcA: UIViewControllerA?

         func removeAnimate() {

              self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
              self.view.removeFromSuperview()
              self.removeFromParentViewController()

              didTransition = true

             if didTransition == true {
               vcA.addVC(). //You have to call addVC() by using the reference of the main view controller.
             }
           }

     }
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! For clarity I thought when a new VC is instantiated it is referenced however this shows me that I am actually creating a copy?

Comment: Not a "copy", it's equivalent to to having to lines of code `let vcA = MyVC()` `let vcB = MyVC()`. It's 2 unrelated instances. The word "copy" implies one is derived from the other.

Comment: @NightHawk95 When a new VC is allocated then it is pointing to different memory location. You have to pass the reference of already allocated one.

Comment: ok, thank you for this clarification! Is there somewhere I can find more literature on these mechanics?

Comment: @NightHawk95 `storyboard.instantiateViewController(_)` will allocation a new instance, it will not point to the existing one

Comment: @NightHawk95 This is about memory management. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

Comment: @NightHawk95 You are welcome :) Please accept the answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> let instVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

This line creates (instantiates) a NEW instance of your MainViewController, it is not your current, displayed MainViewController.

You need to maintain a reference to the first MainViewController (possibly by accessing the `rootViewController` on the main window. And add the new popover to that.